# Open source application for general life planning (calendar, events, to do, goals, money, tickets)

Tags: open-source, calendar, planning

It is not necessary to have every feature I mentioned in the question title.

The point is most probably a nice modern open source calendar application, but the real point is trying to have a complete overview not of one specific project but your entire life in general - how's your financial situation, what upcoming dates are there, even saving critical documents in one place like tickets, registration documents, medical documents, legal documents, etc.

Ideally it would be sort of a combination of a calendar, to-do list, and financial planning app, but at minimum, just a feature-ful open source calendar.

Thank you.